# Is the object of Vector class in Java of static size?

Tags: java, vector

I'm looking for the answer to this question.
something I got from google-
Java.util.Vector Class in Java. The Vector class implements a growable array of objects. Vectors basically falls in legacy classes but now it is fully compatible with collections. They are very similar to ArrayList but Vector is synchronised and have some legacy method which collection framework does not contain.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't quite work out what you mean by "of static size"?  The answer will be different depending on what exactly you're referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Java manages itself memory, keep in mind that we can't exactly know the state of a list/a buffer/an array.

Vectors, like ArrayLists, have an `initialCapacity` that you can pass in parameter in the constructor. From this moment and until the garbage collector runs, the required size to store this `initialCapacity` is allocated to the vector.

Unlike a classic array, Vectors and List are growable. Here is a quick explanation of what happens when you add  an element to your Vector:

- If the Vector is not full, add the element to the Vector
- If the Vector is full, double the size of the Vector

  - In terms of memory management, it means that you need to re-allocate the Vector. If the space after the Vector is free, the Vector will use this space. Otherwise, another chunk of memory will be allocated and the entire Vector will be moved to this chunk.

You can change the amount by which the Vector grows in the constructor (`capacityIncrement`). The default value is 2, so the capacity grows really fast.

Vectors are synchronized, but you should not iterate them with an Iterator : They're not fail-safe (If the structure of the Vector is modified while iterating, the Iterator will not be updated). That's why using Locks and ArrayList are usually safer (If you know how to use locks correctly) than using Vectors.

You can get more details here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html